# Editing CSS on Wordpress for a single page

Tags: css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

So i am trying to apply CSS to a single page in wordpress and i am having a little trouble doing so, if anyone can direct me in the right direction that would be great.

I have this in the main theme css folder

```
.content h3 {
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    color: #444;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 21px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

and i have put at the bottom of the CSS file this to effect a single page

```
.page-id-437 .h3.gv-field-3-1{
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    color: #444;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 21px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

EDIT: i should probably add that .h3.gv-field-3-1 is the specific field that i want to edit and 437 is the page id that i want it to go into

Comment: When you added the style for .page-id-437 .h3.gv-field-3-1 at the bottom of your style sheet, you didn't happen to add it inside a media query, did you? Also, are you saying that these styles are not applying? Could you test it out by applying !important; at the end of each one? If that doesn't show your styles then you're not selecting them properly (possibly because they don't have those classes).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your approach. Is `h3` a class you have or should that be targeting an h3 with the class `.gv-field-3-1`. Also, are you sure your body has the page class?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I do have a h3 class but i am thinking that your last point is what makes this not work. Would you mind expanding on "Also, are you sure your body has the page class?"

Comment: in order to have those classes come up on the body you need to call the body class function `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` so check your template to see if it has that. If not add it in and you should see your css.

Comment: so basically i am trying to edit the css of a plugin on a single page. would you recommend that i add the body class function to the theme or the specific plugin php?

Comment: i always add it to the theme, then you have a system on every page to target stuff based on page, if it's a child or ancestor etc. Put the body_class function on and inspect the body tag on different pages. You will see it adds some handy classes

Comment: hmmm alright sounds good, do you have a good link or tutorial kind of thing that lays out what i should actually put into the theme? sorry i am really newb

Comment: I was under the impression that he does have the body class for that page because I'm not sure how he would have gotten .page-id-437 if he didn't?

Comment: as boring of an answer as it is the Wordpress docs explain everything pretty well. http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: alright ill read it and post back to see. I got the .page-id-437 from firefox's firebug

Comment: so...I've added <body <?php body_class(); ?>> to the end of my functions.php in my themes folder and i reloaded the page that i wanted to edit and got an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /dcatlt/3rdparty/atldevwp/wp-content/themes/fw_mazaya/functions.php on line 268"

Comment: no no no. You put it on your <body> tag, in your html. commonly in index.php or header.php (or something similar). Functions.php is just for php functions

Comment: Ahhhh i got you. Well i've looked through every file in my themes folder....is <tbody></tbody> the same thing?

Comment: nope thats for tables. are you working with one of the themes that comes with WP?

Comment: nah its a custom one that i found online called mazaya i suppose i can try to go back to the site i downloaded it from and look for it over there. thanks for all the help so far im sure ill have some more questions :/